# Using a lambda expression as a function argument

Tags: python, regex, lambda

I am having trouble understanding how lambda expressions work when they are used as function arguments. For example:

```
import re
rep = {"hi": "hello", "ya": "you"}
text = 'hi how are ya'
keys = re.compile('hi|ya')
text = keys.sub(lambda m: rep[m.group(0)], text)
print(text)
```

replaces 'hi' and 'ya' with 'hello' and 'you', returning

> ```
> "hello how are you"
> ```

I am confused as to why this works because we never specified what values `m` takes and how the `re.sub()` function interprets this when the first argument is supposed to be a string.

Comment: A `lambda` expression is just an anonymous function, any lambda function can be written as a full function definition. Note, in full function definitions, you don't specifiy what values the parameters take either (well, you can use type *hints* but you are free to ignore those, you get the point). Anyway, `regex.sub` is written to accept an argument that is a function. that's why it works. You can write your own functions that are suppose to take other functions and do stuff with them. try it

Answer (score 4):

From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

You can think of lambdas as single-line functions as they're functionally equivalent, so

```
lambda m: rep[m.group(0)]
```

becomes

```
def unnamed_function(m):
    return rep[m.group(0)]
```

and `m` is assigned as a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to iBug's nice answer, you say why the first argument can work with a non-string object, this is also the case with `timeit`, and other stuff.

Also, `lambda`s are equivalent to functions, so basically you're putting a function, even if you manually did a function and put the function name in it, it will work.

Note: there's a non-regex no-module way of doing this thing:

```
' '.join([rep.get(i,i) for i in text.split()])
```

Demo:

```
>>> rep = {"hi": "hello", "ya": "you"}
>>> text = 'hi how are ya'
>>> ' '.join([rep.get(i,i) for i in text.split()])
'hello how are you'
>>>
```